# how to put plugins and libraries for connection to firebase?

Tags: android

which plugins and libraries (and versions) I need to put to connect to firebase?

I put this :   classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0` and classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.1`
and this is [printscr](http://prntscr.com/p0s40k).

---

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not complicate yourself. There are various ways to add dependencies for firebase and connect your app to firebase. The most easiest and simplest way is through firebase assistant in android studio.
Please follow the steps below

1. open the android studio and click on **Tools** in the upper left corner
2. Now click on the **Firebase** option in the drop down menu.
3. A menu will appear on the right side of screen. It will show various servicesthat Firebase offers. Choose the desired service.
4. Now Click on the **Connect to Firebase** option in the menu of desired service.
5. Add the dependencies of your service by clicking on the **Add dependencies**

Its very easy process to follow.

Comment: I did that and have app on console, but although its write that dependencies are set up  correctly  ( http://prntscr.com/p0t6e8  ) still can't launch app and have lots of errors....

Comment: Java conpiler detected 5 errors as shown in the image. Please click on these error to show the logs. The currently visible logs are gradle error. Once java compiler errors fixed, gradle errors will fixed automatically. So please post the logs of java compiler.

Comment: So clearly its errors in your MainActivity. Go to your MainActivity and check what causing these error. One way to click on the error line and press Alt Enter to open fix suggestions for the error.

Comment: Are you using firebase database or firestore?

Answer (score 0):

You forget migrate to android'x
got to refactor and migrate

Comment: how to migrate to androidx?

Comment: refactor->migrate

Comment: after that you can set a back up,and after android studio will show usages and in the buttom you should press do refactor.